# Laravel - how to link to specific ID?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have *id* with name *regModal* in all of my pages.  Now , I can access this id with clicking on specific link.   Here is my code:

**views/includes/header.blade.php:**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#regModal">register</a>
<div id="regModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
.
.
.
</div>
```

But I want to access it with `#regModal` in all of my pages. for example if user insert : `mywebsite.com/#regModal` he/she can access to this modal.

How to do that?

Comment: This is totally unclear. What is it with id `regModal`, what do you want to access. At least show some code.

Comment: This should be done with js by checking hash (`document.location.hash`)

Comment: @afn, why did you delete question with my answer about phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

Js object `document.location` has a special property called `hash`, which stores hash - a `#` sign and a string which follows a `#` sign.

You can access it with `document.location.hash` and check it's value. For example:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    if ( document.location.hash == "#regModal" ) {
        // open your form or whatever
    }
} );
```